# See the memory used by a C program with gprof

Tags: c, memory-management, gprof

I am running my C program and I want to see the memory used by this. I am using the profiler [`gprof`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.28/gprof/index.html). Is it possible with `gprof`? Or maybe I have to study the [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) profile?

Comment: My impression is that `gprof` is primarily used for timing performance and not for measuring the amount of memory used.  Valgrind is more concerned with memory.  I've only used it for its 'memory abuse' detection; there are other ways to use it and one of those may be appropriate for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go down the Valgrind route, Massif is the tool to use:

`valgrind --tool=massif your_app -your_options`

Answer (score 1):

You can use gprof - but you need to ensure that you've compiled your c program with the correct options for profiling (-pg).  For example:

```
cc -o cprogram program.c othercode.c -g -pg
```

To use gprof, check the man pages - but, in short:

```
gprof <options> [executable-file [profile-data-files...]] [> outfile]
```

I hope that this helps!

Comment: How does this help the OP to view memory used ?

Comment: I interpreted the question as being how to profile the running application.  If all the OP wants to do is see the memory used then gprof (and the associated compiler/linker options) are unnecessary because 'top' will suffice. Even valgrind needs the -pg options to be used though.

Comment: You may also want to check http://valgrind-users.narkive.com/MPnV7HOw/gcc-pg-valgrind-errors

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am reading about gprof. I think gprof can t measure used memory. This is just for the time spend for each functions and the calls of the functions. I am going to see the valgrid profile.